# text shifts up when input tag removed

Tags: html

When I remove the input tag from the label the layout height and I cannot figure out why the height changes.  Is there something special that happens with height alignment when an input tag is placed with a label?

from:

```
    <div class=" pull-right">
      <label class="pull-left"><small>FROM:</small><input type="date"></label>
      <label class="pull-left"><small>TO:</small><input type="date"></label>
    </div>
```

[image]

to:

```
    <div class=" pull-right">
      <label class="pull-left"><small>FROM:</small><input type="date"></label>
      <label class="pull-left"><small>TO:</small></label>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't do this for me in Chrome or Firefox. What browser do you see this in?

Comment: i did it in firefox.  thanks .. let me check this by stripping out the rest of the html

Comment: thanks it's my bad.  other css was causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your css file

```
position: absolute;
width:???px;
```